# Using itemlookup in Amazon Product API with php

Tags: php, javascript, amazon-product-api, dom

All I want is something like the following returned on the same page:

> Save 8.91%
>
> <strike>Retail Price: $599.00</strike>
>
> Price: $549.99
>
> Total Savings: $49.01

Because I don't know PHP very well I had a really hard time following the documentation. I got stuck for a few hours on trying to figure out the signature process. I think I understand it, it's a security feature used for authenticating your identity. And it's stored as a SHA-1 hash so you need some sort of function to make sense of that. Of course in my case, easier said than done.

But maybe what I'm trying to do is a lot simpler than the example that's in the documentation anyway, as they use a the ItemSearch operation which involves form input. This seems more straight forward.

I'm going to try to explain this process and please correct me if my understanding is wrong. So a php script is ran and it makes a request to the Amazon product API for certain details, it authenticates you and returns you the data that you wanted in some sort of variable, then that variable is parsed into XML? And then you use javascript to parse that XML and to put it into the HTML DOM where it will display on the same page.

Is this approximately it? No?

So how would I actually translate this into code?

Resources I've been reading:
http://www.kennylucius.com/a/AAWS_signed_URL_function

docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RequestAuthenticationArticle.html

docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/GSG/ImplementinganA2SRequest.html

Okay so making requests through signedURLs is simple enough... And it returns stuff that I'm looking for in XML which I can style, awesome. But how do I do that in PHP? I found one more helpful resource which quickly goes over the API library.

codediesel.com/php/accessing-amazon-product-advertising-api-in-php/

From that article and the documentation I think this is what the general process is:

> 1) Create an object with a request in it
>
> 2) Add the different parameters you'd like in your request
>
> 3) Send request while authenticating your request

Comment: Why is this tagged JavaScript if you're going to use PHP to fetch the information from the Amazon Product API?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote or at least improved a bunch of code to access the Amazon Product API. The latest version is in GitHub, it was part of [my web mashup codebase](http://www.muschamp.ca/Muskie/webMashups.html).

It has methods such as:

- public function getItemByUpc($upc_code, $product_type)
- public function getItemByAsin($asin_code)
- public function getItemAttributesByAsin($asin_code)
- public function getRelatedItemsByAsin($asin_code)
- public function getRelatedTracksToAsin($asin_code)
- public function getItemByKeyword($keyword, $product_type)
- public function getMP3sForAlbumByArtist($albumTitle, $artist)
- public function getMP3ForSongByArtist($songTitle, $artist)
- public function getBookForKeyword($keyword)
- public function getAlbumCoverByArtistAndTitle($artist, $title)
- public function getInfoForSongwriter($artist)
- public function getDVDCoverByTitle($title)
- public function getDVDCoverByTitleAndDirector($title, $director)

Based on those examples and the various helper methods that do the heavy lifting you should be able to get most anything Amazon lets you get nowadays from the Amazon Product API. They don't give you everything, direct links to MP3 previews no longer seems to work (be possible). The documentation perhaps isn't the best, you need to understand Response Groups and Categories and the difference between and ItemSearch and an ItemLookUp sometimes you have to make multiple queries to get all the information. I've written a lot of code to access the Amazon Product API, check it out it is based on Sameer's code, I think he rolled in some of my changes/fixes/additions but not all. Different people try to get different information out of the API...